# How to get form submit object keys and iterate over them in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <label for="Identity">Identity</label>
      <select class="input-combobox" id="parentAttr" value="Identity" name="Identity">
         <? var dropdownOptions = getDropdownOptions(); ?>
          <option name="Identity" value="placeholder"></option>
          <? 
            for(i=0; i<dropdownOptions.length;i++){
          ?>
          <option value= "<?= dropdownOptions[i] ?> "> <?= dropdownOptions[i] ?> </option>
          <? } ?>
      </select>
      <input name="myFile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
      }
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
    </script>
```

and in Code.gs

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log(formObject);    //logs {myFile=FileUpload, Identity=c } Those are the values I picked in my form. 

}
```

After I log the formObject. I want to Log formObject.keys- im not sure what the call is as the formObject doesn't seem to be a valid javascript object. Further I would like to do something like `for (var key in formObject.keys) {execute something}` but Im not sure how to iterate through this formObject either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually tried this and run into any errors? The for loop for iterating over object properties is

```
for(var key in object) {

Logger.log(key); // logs property name
Logger.log(object[key]); //logs value for the property


}
```

Another option to log property names

```
Logger.log(Object.keys(yourFormObject));
```

Comment: this works thanks! Can you point me to where you found this? Especially Object.keys(yourFormObject)? I am having trouble navigating the google apps script documentation

Comment: You won't find this in Apps Script docs, because GAS is just plain JavaScript with some custom objects (pseudo classes like Document, Spreadsheet, GmailApp etc) that Google added to simplify interaction with its services. If you'd like to explore JavaScript in depth, Mozilla Developer Network is a great resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object